# what all changes I need to make in php.ini file in order to use imagecopyresampled for images with size greater than 2 MB..?

Tags: php, image

I have already done following changes in php.ini file in my system using solutions given to similar problems.

- max_execution_time=60
- memory_limit=1280M
- post_max_size=1000M
- upload_max_filesize=1000M

Now the image gets uploaded and moved to a specific folder but when I resize it using imagecreatejpeg,imagecreatetruecolor and imagecopyresampled functions,The resultant image that is created is a black image of required pixels size.I guess the only problem is with imagecopyresampled function because the code is working for small images and even for images with higher pixel quality (with size just less than 2MB).

**Note**-I cannot use Imagick() function as described in some of the solutions of similar questions.

Comment: Please post your code and the image you are trying to resize so it can be tested on another system.

Comment: @timclutton I actually tried afterwards on my friend's machine and its working perfectly fin.It seems I should reinstall xampp on my pc.Thank you for your comment